# How to export a Neo4j DB to a .gexf file? (Without command lines, only code)

Tags: neo4j

without using tools like Gremlin i wonder how to export my DB created with Neo4j to a file (prefered .gexf) in order to open it in a soft like Gephi.
Im searching code on the web but i don't find any.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be okay with GraphML? You said you'd like to not use Gremlin, but Tinkerpop's blueprints has a class for writing GraphML files from your Neo4j graph, and Gephi supports GraphML importing.

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseService("/graphLocation");
Graph graph = new Neo4jGraph(db );
GraphMLWriter.outputGraph(graph, "/graphMLOutputLocation.gml");
```

This uses Tinkerpop blueprints which can be imported in Maven.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
   <artifactId>blueprints-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but i had to make some changes because of versions problems.
I had to add the blueprints-neo4j-graph dependency 2.2.0! (the 2.3.0 doesn't work)

I generated the graph.gml but i cant' read it with Gephi! -> Error servere. When i open the graph.gml with notepad i see the edges and nodes are ok. So i don't understand why Gephi don't open the .gml... I opened a random .gml file on the web it did the same problem...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the extension, I thought it was shortened. Glad to hear it worked.